# How to save image from server to local storage Ionic 2 with cordova-plugin-http

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I use cordova-plugin-http plugin for communicating with HTTP server
[ionicframework docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#downloadFile)

But downloadFile method doesn't work. Maybe, local file path not set, help me.

My code:

```
downLoad() {
    this.http.downloadFile('http://example.com/files/files/image.jpg', {}, {}, 'image.jpg')
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data) ;
    })
    .catch(error => {

        console.log(error) ;

    });

}
```

Error was in the exists of a file http://example.com/files/files/image.jpg

Now there is another problem - how to save the image in the Photo Gallery?

Comment: What does console.error outoput? By the way, console.log(success) will output an error, as long that success is not defined. I guess that you should have written console.log('success') or console.log(data)

Comment: Error was in the exists of a file `http://example.com/files/files/image.jpg`

Now there is another problem - how to save the image in the Photo Gallery?